# Print json value without quotes for python

Tags: python, json

I have the following json:

```
{
  "email": "lalalalal@gmail.com"
}
```

and little test script:

```
file = open('/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Test/newfile.json')
x = json.load(file)
y = repr(x['email'])
print('My test email is ' + y)
```

I receive next output:

```
My test email is 'lalalalal@gmail.com'
```

My question is:

How to receive JSON value data (print also) without ordinary quotes in output?

To receive:

**My test email is lalalalal@gmail.com**

Comment: You don't use `repr()`!

Comment: Sorry, don't understand...

Comment: Remove the `repr()` call. That is what is adding the quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you, that's fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use repr. You can get the value without repr

```
x['email']
```